# How can I show the text of a "Condition flow" when using "Together Workflow Editor"

Tags: java, workflow, bpmn

I am a user of the "Together Workflow Editor". Recently I got a new requirement. I have to make the "Condition flow" show its name. For example, this is the original graph:

[The original graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOuiz.png)

​And now I want the graph below:

[The graph that is with text on the "Condition flow"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmVkG.png)

I tried my best, but I can't find the method. ​So if anyone has a solution for my problem, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By sending an email to the author of "Together Workflow Editor", I have solved this problem.The solution is:

Edit the file "%Install_Folder%\config\default\togwegraphcontroller.properties",
the original file is:
[image: The original file]

And change it to:
[image: The edited file]

Then click this image button:
[image: The Image Button to show the name of "Condition flow"]

Now you can see the name of the "Condition flow":
[image: The Final Image]